# How to pass data to React Hook

Tags: react-hooks

I am new to React and I try to implement following code where I get axios response:

```
response.data
```

returns expected array. But when I try to use 'setRankings' setter to put data into 'rankings' array it is empty (undefined in console)

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Wrapper from "./Wrapper";
import axios from "axios";


const Rankings = () => {

    const [rankings, setRankings] = React.useState([])

    useEffect( () => {
        (
            async () => {

                const response = await axios.get('rankings')
                //console.log(response.data) // returns expected data
                const x = setRankings((response.data))
                console.log(x)  // returns undefined
                //console.log(rankings) // also empty array. why?
            }

        )();

    }, []);



    return (
        .....
            
    );
};

export default Rankings;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Setting a state requires a re-render, and the new state is only available then. Move `console.log(rankings)` out of the `useEffect`, and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect when a change happens to your state. Add a new useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(rankings)
}, [rankings]) # It'll be called when rankings get updated
```

Comment: If I do this, something strange happens in the console: The console.log containing data, gets output about 27 times. And after that comes 400 error from server.

Comment: Did you add another useEffect hook or just added the [rankings] array to the existing one ? What you need to do is adding a new useEffect hook. Adding [rankings] only will lead to an infinite loop..